# PHP returns blank page if i increase attachments size limit

Tags: php

I'm using Gmail API with PHP and trying to get all attachments for retrieved threads but if i set limit size for attachments more than 1.3 mb my code returns me a blank page with no content and status code 200. I save attachments as base64 encoded string to replace all embed images and attachments.

```
          //some code before

          //for attachments in latest message in a thread
          if(isset($data['threads'][$keyT][$keyA]['attachments'])){
                $attachments=$data['threads'][$keyT][$keyA]['attachments'];
                for($i=0;$i<count($attachments);$i++){
                    $a=$attachments[$i];
                    if(
                        (
                            $a['mimetype']=='image/gif' ||
                            $a['mimetype']=='image/jpeg' ||
                            $a['mimetype']=='image/pjpeg' ||
                            $a['mimetype']=='image/png' ||
                            $a['mimetype']=='image/svg+xml'
                        ) && $a['size']<1500000
                    ){
                        $data['threads'][$keyT][$keyA]['attachments'][$i]['data']=$this->getAttachmentInner(
                            $data['threads'][$keyT][$keyA]['attachments'][$i]['attachmentId'],$data['threads'][$keyT][$keyA]['gmailmsgid'],
                            $detail['redirect_url'],$detail['app_name'],$detail['secret'],$detail['credentials']
                        );
                    }else{
                        echo "<pre>";
                        print_r($a);
                        echo "</pre>";
                    }
                }
            }
            // for embed images
            for ($k=0;$k<count($data['threads']);$k++){
                for($j=0;$j<count($data['threads'][$k]);$j++){
                    if(isset($data['threads'][$k][$j]['attachments'])){
                        $attachments=$data['threads'][$k][$j]['attachments'];
                        for($i=0;$i<count($attachments);$i++){
                            $a=$attachments[$i];
                            if(
                                (
                                    $a['mimetype']=='image/gif' ||
                                    $a['mimetype']=='image/jpeg' ||
                                    $a['mimetype']=='image/pjpeg' ||
                                    $a['mimetype']=='image/png' ||
                                    $a['mimetype']=='image/svg+xml'
                                ) && $a['size']<1500000 && $a['class']=='embed' && isset($a['embed_id'])
                            ){
                                $data['threads'][$k][$j]['attachments'][$i]['data']=$this->getAttachmentInner(
                                    $data['threads'][$k][$j]['attachments'][$i]['attachmentId'],$data['threads'][$k][$j]['gmailmsgid'],
                                    $detail['redirect_url'],$detail['app_name'],$detail['secret'],$detail['credentials']
                                );
                            }else{

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

However if size in condition less than 1.5 mb my script works ok.

```
&& $a['size']<500000
```

Also I have these settings for PHP, but they don't help:

```
set_time_limit (300);

ini_set('memory_limit', '96M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '96M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '96M');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', 100024*1024);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Can those three be set in your PHP? Have you tried setting them in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrGlass yes, but i tried to set this into .htaccess and no effect

Comment: Have you added some `echo` statements to make sure you are getting past all of your `if`s as expected?

Comment: @MrGlass yeah my sript starts with `echo 'wtf';` and it was an error, i  puted my iniset before all outputs and it worked. thnks

Comment: I meant add an echo to see if your `if()` statements are all working the way you expected.

Comment: It's actually not, i just got new email and now im getting blank page on next page. As long as if statements they works correctly, tested with echo and 0.5 md size